# Spring AOP: get access to argument names

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I'm using Spring 3.x, Java 6.

I have an @Around aspect with the following joinpoint:

```
@Around("execution(public * my.service.*.*Connector.*(..))")
```

So, I'm basically interested in intercepting all calls to public methods of classes with the class name ending with "Connector". So far so good.

Now, in my aspect I would like to access the actual argument names of the methods:

```
public doStuff(String myarg, Long anotherArg)
```

**myarg** and **anotherArg**

I understand that using:

```
CodeSignature signature = (CodeSignature)jointPoint.getSignature();
return signature.getParameterNames();
```

will actually work but only if I compile the code with the "*-g*" flag (full debug) and I would rather not do it.

Is there any other way to get access to that kind of runtime information.

Thanks
L

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this :-(. It is a well known limitation of JVM/bytecode - argument names can't be obtained using reflection, as they are not always stored in bytecode (in the contrary to method/class names).

As a workaround several frameworks/specification introduce custom annotations over arguments like [`WebParam`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jws/WebParam.html) (`name` property) or [`PathParam`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html).

For the time being all you can get without annotations is an array of values.

Comment: I'm not sure here, but I think it's true that they can't be obtained using reflection while it isn't necessarily true that they aren't stored in the bytecode. As mentioned in the question, they are stored when compiled with (at least) `javac -g:vars ...` so they can be displayed in debuggers. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, I slightly edited my original answer.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail about "pathParam" and "WebParam"?

Comment: Probably in 2011 this answer was correct, but since the `-parameters` compiler switch has been introduced (also mentioned by @junkgui), you can a) compile parameter info into your class files and b) get access to that info from current AspectJ versions. But the question was about Java 6, so for that version this answer is still correct.

Answer (score 5):

Check the implementations of `org.springframework.core.ParameterNameDiscoverer`.

Annotations like `@RequestParam` used by spring inspect the parameter name if no `value` is set. So `@RequestParam String foo` will in fact fetch the request parameter named "foo". It uses the `ParameterNameDiscoverer` mechanism. I'm just not sure which of the implementations are used, by try each of them.

The `LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer` reads the `.class` and uses asm to inspect the names.

So, it is possible. But make sure to cache this information (for example - store a parameter name in a map, with key = class+method+parameter index).

But, as it is noted in the docs, you need the debug information. From the docs of `@PathVariable`:

> The matching of method parameter names to URI Template variable names can only be done if your code is compiled with debugging enabled. If you do not have debugging enabled, you must specify the name of the URI Template variable name in the @PathVariable annotation in order to bind the resolved value of the variable name to a method parameter

So, if you really don't want to include that information, Tomasz Nurkiewicz's answer explains the workaround.

Comment: Thanks Bozhidar, the Javadoc for the LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer says:
Returns
 * <code>null</code> if the class file was compiled without debug information

Comment: @Luciano Fiandesio yes, true. I'll update to include a bit more info

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8 there is a new compiler flag that allows additional metadata to be stored with byte code and these parameter names can be extracted using the Parameter object in reflection.  See [JDK 8 spec](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/118). In newer versions of hibernate org.springframework.core.ParameterNameDiscoverer uses this feature.  To use it compile using `javac` with this flag:

```
-parameters                Generate metadata for reflection on method parameters
```

Access parameters using reflection's [Parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if its a best way, but I added a Annotation on my method:

My Annotation:

```
@Retention (RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target (ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ReadApi
{
    String[] paramNames() default "";
}

@ReadApi (paramNames={"name","id","phone"})
public Address findCustomerInfo(String name, String id, String phone)
{ ..... }
```

And in the Aspect:

```
@Around("aspect param && @annotation(readApi)")
public Object logParams(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,
        ReadApi readApi) 
{
    //use pjp.getArgs() and readApi.paramNames();
}
```

This is probably a hack but i did not want to compile with more options to get information. Anyways, its working well for me. Only downside is that i need to keep the names in annotation and method in sync.