# Getting the values of the parameters passed to the method while handling exception with Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-aop

In my aspect class's method I want to get the values of the parameters and the name of the parameters. 
Names are still ok if I don't get but I need to get the values of the parameters passed is it possible?
(There is not issue with ptCut expression , the method is getting called i checked with sysouts)

My Aspect method is something like this :

```
    public void excpetionHappened(Exception e) {
    // Log the exception
    // log the name of the method name/signature which caused the exception
    // log the value of the input parameters to the method
    // wrap and throw new exctn

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can find your answer from this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030638/spring-aop-get-access-to-argument-names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a around advice.

This makes it possible to access the parameter while handling the exception.

```
public aspect ExceptionReporterAspect {

    /** The name of the used logger. */
    public final static String LOGGER_NAME = "AspectJExceptionLogger";

    /** Logger used to log messages. */
    private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(LOGGER_NAME);

    pointcut stringRequestHandler() : 
        execution (@RequestMapping Object the.package..*(..));

    Object around(): objectRequestHandler(){
        try {
            return proceed();
        } catch (Exception ex){
            Signature sig = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
            Object[] args = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();

            String location = sig.getDeclaringTypeName() + '.' + sig.getName() + ", args=" + Arrays.toString(args);
            LOGGER.warn("(AOP detected) exception within " + location, ex);

               throw(ex)
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. It helps but do we have something to get parameter names also :)?

Comment: This is discussed in the question mentioned in the comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030638/spring-aop-get-access-to-argument-names

Comment: But it doesn't help much as it talks about webservice related things.

Comment: I think it is clear: Question: "Spring AOP: get access to argument names?"  Answer: "Unfortunately you can't do this :-(. It is a well known limitation of JVM/bytecode - argument names can't be obtained using reflection,"  And then there is the second answer from Bozho, he shows how Spring overcome this problem. -- In the end, it is not webservice related.